# Why do some servers run both Tomcat and also Apache Web Server?

Tags: java, apache, web-services, tomcat

Tomcat is used for running Java servlets, but it also has the webserver functionality built in, so it can run independently. However, I see several articles on how to integrate Apache Webserver with Tomcat? What's the purpose of doing this? Does it improve performance?

I am using Tomcat for serving WebServices.

Comment: Performance is definitely one of the reasons, as Apache will typically be a whole lot faster for serving static content (.html files, images etc).

Comment: And why would Apache HTTP be "a whole lot faster"? Its just static content, basically just transferring raw bytes. What would Apache HTTP do more efficient than Tomcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat is a fine Servlet container, but there are a lot of things an Apache httpd can do better (easier and/or faster).

For example Apache can handle security, SSL, provide load balancing, URL rewriting etc.

You can also split content: you can have your Apache httpd to serve *static content* like images, static html, js etc. and leave the *dynamic content* (like servlets, jsp etc.) to Tomcat. This also has the advantage that a failure in Tomcat will not render your whole web site unusable / unavailable (just the servlets/jsp pages).

You can also separate the 2 and thus increase security: you can run Apache httpd on one server (which would be reachable on the internet) and direct it to another server running Tomcat, invisible from the outside.

Comment: Thank you. Can you you run Apache and Tomcat on different servers? Does that help with performance?

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Quite often a separate web server is used to distribute traffic or allow for extra functionality provided by [Apache Web Server modules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/), which there are plenty. It can also be more performant, depending on your use case.

In short, even if Tomcat has the basic web server functionalities, Apache Web Server can also do other things Tomcat cannot.